# How to check whether some date is in the current calendar month or not in oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to print records which have the current calendar month as the enrolled month.

I used `sysdate` for this function. But, I'm not sure if that is correct or not.

My code would be,

```
select * from student where sysdate,trunc('mm') = enrolled_month;
```

I just need some way to print current month using `sysdate` function.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show sample data from the `enrolled_month` column?  Why are you storing the month separately from the rest of the enroll date?

Comment: January, February, March etc.

Comment: What if there are rows in the table from August 2010? Should the query include those if the current month is August 2018?

Comment: what *exactly* is the datatype for `enrolled_month`? varchar2 or char?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another option using `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Month') = enrolled_month;
```

But I don't think it's a good idea to store the enrollment month name (and perhaps the other components) separate from the enrollment date.  Just store the date once, and then use Oracle's date functions to work that data.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you need `EXTRACT` function:

```
select * 
  from student 
 where enrolled_month = extract(month from sysdate);
```

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, `extract(month from sysdate)` returns an integer(i.e.`8`), but not `August`. So, it doesn't work as you've pointed.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan yes, if `August` is needed then it doesn't return needed output. In question it was stated `'mm'` so I thought that a number is needed as the output, not a string. Thank you. Tim posted an answer that uses a `TO_CHAR` function and that one returns string.

Comment: Ah, after Tim's comment, it's revealed that's string, OK.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MON') FROM DUAL;
```

or

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') FROM DUAL;
```

or

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;
```

However, you may also need to consider the year if your STUDENT table contains data for more than one year.

Answer (score 4):

Besides all the good answers of our colleagues, you may hold `enrolled_month` columns' values in your local languages(during population of the column `enrolled_month`), and match in the *where* clause with the contribution of `nls_date_language` argument of *to_char* function as :

```
select enrolled_month as "Month_Hindi"
  from student 
 where to_char(sysdate, 'Month','nls_date_language=Hindi') = enrolled_month;

Month_Hindi
-----------
अगस्त
```

or

```
select enrolled_month as "Month_Tamil" 
  from student 
 where to_char(sysdate, 'Month','nls_date_language=Tamil') = enrolled_month;

Month_Tamil
-----------
ஆகஸ்ட்
```

considering that you're from *Sri Lanka*.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you to consider this approach:

```
select s.*
from student s
where enrolled_month >= trunc(sysdate, 'mon') and
      enrolled_month < trunc(sysdate, 'mon') + interval '1' month;
```

Why is this better than other approaches?  The function calls are all on `sysdate`, not on the table column.  This means that Oracle can take advantage of an index on `enrolled_month` -- and that could be a significant improvement in performance.